# Pagination with Java API for ElasticSearch

Tags: java, playframework, elasticsearch

I am trying to use elastic search module in the play framework for searching books and I have the following method to perform the search in the controller which returns me a list of books based upon the search string entered by the user

```
public static void bookList(String search){
    SearchResults<Book> searchResult =  ElasticSearch.search(QueryBuilders.queryString(search)  , Book.class);
    List<Book> bookList = searchResult.objects  ;
    render(bookList);
}
```

Now I need to perform pagination on the results obtained . How do I go about doing that using the Java API ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Elasticsearch module documentation for Play:

> Call ElasticSearch.query() and subsequently set query parameters (e.g.
>   paging)

So in your case, you want to retrieve j searchresults from i:

```
SearchResults<Book> searchResult =  ElasticSearch.query(QueryBuilders.queryString(search), Book.class).from(i).size(j).fetch();
```